# Plumbing T-fitting install/location issue

Tags: plumbing

We have new pex? plumbing lines being installed, in the picture is a T-fitting that is wedged into the stud. Due to the bend from the incoming line, there is a lot of pressure that is “pushing” the T-fitting against the stud. I fear over time the pressure will cause the fitting or connection to weaken or break.

Any truth to what I’m thinking?
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a "T" fitting not a valve. Show how you adjust it. I think it will be OK as installed.

Comment: Sorry, t fitting.  I can barely budge it, the line feeding the left is pushing it into the stud and I can barely wiggle it in its place.